# CakePHP form Day, Month, Year Validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am using CakePHP 2.3.9 and the CakePHP form helper to create a registration form.

I am using the built in form validation for all fields but I can't get it working for the day, month and year entries.

The fields should be required and not empty. I have correct validation working on all other fields (normal text input and selects).

Here's the inputs from the view:

```
   <?= $this->Form->day('dateOfBirth', array('class'=>'date-of-birth', 'empty' => 'day')); ?>
   <?= $this->Form->month('dateOfBirth', array('class'=>'date-of-birth','empty' => 'month')); ?>
   <?= $this->Form->year('dateOfBirth','2014','1901', array('class'=>'date-of-birth','empty' => 'year')); ?>
```

Here's the current(not working) validation in the model:

```
    'dateOfBirth' => array(
           'rule' => 'notempty',
           'required' => true
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Modal validation [**nonEmpty**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation::notEmpty) rule should be like this

```
var $validate = array(
    'dateOfBirth' => array(
    'rule' => 'notEmpty',
    'required' => true
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `notEmpty` instead of `notempty`!

Comment: It's CI, but yeah, one should still respect the casing.

Comment: there are places, where it matters, such as a typo in magic function names called on the model, I don't know this particular case, but it's strongly advised to keep the standards

Comment: I know that, and you are absolutely right. Its still not the *right* answer ;)

Comment: my bad. I've changed my code to reflect best practice but the issues is still there as Mark stated

Comment: I'm not sure, but please try removing these array elements: `'empty' => 'day'`, they might interfere with `notEmpty`

Answer (score 0):

you can do in this way also,

```
echo $this->Form->input('dateOfBirth',array('dateFormat' => 'YDM','maxYear'=>date('Y'),'minYear'=>'1901','empty'=>'--Select--','label'=>'Select Birth Date'));
```

**model rule,**

```
var $validate = array(
        'dateOfBirth' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',   // or you can use 'rule' => array('date'),
        'required' => true,
        'message'=>'Please Select BirthDate'
        )
   );
```

**Note :** The above rule It will **validate proper date**. but problem is you can't define multiple empty values for the dropdowns generated here.Instead they will be populated as "--Select--" as empty value for all of three.If you are ok with it then you can implement the same.